# Magento 2 Round off layered navigation max price in the price range

Tags: attributes, magento2.3, price, layered-navigation, filter

I want to round off the price range values in the layered navigation. Now it is showing as below

```
$40.00 - $49.99
$50.00 - $59.99
$60.00 - $69.99
$70.00 - $79.99
$90.00 and above
```

[image]

I want the following format.

```
$40.00 - $50
$51.00 - $60
$61 - $70
$71 - $90
$91.00 and above
```

How can I do it?

I am using magento 2.3.2. 
I have configured the Price Navigation Step Calculation field as "Automatic (equalize price ranges)".

Please help me to resolve this

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Let me know if you find the solution.

Comment: @Nayem Please override the class Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Price

Comment: could you please tell which code to override?

Answer (score 0):

I have override the **_renderRangeLabel** function in the class

```
Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Price.php.
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to set below configuration

> Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Layered navigation >
>   price navigation step calculation

[image]

I hope this settings help of you.

Comment: I have tried this. But it is not round off the values